# How I can filter a DataTable and create a new dataTable in ASP.NET with Linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, listview, datatable

hi i have a problem in my asp.net application.

I have a DataTable and I want to filter this table with linq to datatable.

my DataTable has this structure:

User | Licenses | Department | Time | Telephonenumber | Location

I want a new datatable with no dublicate entries in department. For example:

this are three rows in the basic dataTable

```
userA | 1 | IT        | 4min | 0123/123 | germany 
userB | 1 | Marketing | 3min | 0232/232 | germany 
userC | 1 | IT        | 1min | 0233/233 | germany
```

this I want:

Department | Licenses

```
It         | 2 
Marketing  | 1
```

That means that the use licenes must be calculate.

Here is my Code:

**UPDATE:**

```
 var query = from row in catia_user_table.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row.Field<string>("Department") into grp
                            orderby grp.Key
                            select new
                            {
                                Department = grp.Key,
                                Licenses = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<int>("Licenses"))

                            };

                    DataTable tb = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

The think the Problem is that every row in my DataTable is from Typ string or is that not so importent?

Comment: You need to group it by department in your query. CopyToDataTable() is right as it would create new DataTable based on filtered values. Plz comment if i understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Krishnraj Rana said, you just need to group by Department, then use `Sum` operator to calculate total licenses for each Department. See below:

```
var query = catia_user_table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(n => n.Department)
                            .Select(g => new
                             {
                                Department = g.Key,
                                Licenses = g.Sum(n => n.Licensec)
                             }).ToList();
```

Comment: System.Data.DataTable don't content a Definition for "GroupBy" and it couldn't find a Extentionmethod with "GroupBy" with a Argument from Typ "System.Data.DataTable" accept. (Using-Direktive or an Assemblyreference)

Comment: hi @Tarasov, try to add `AsEnumerable` before `GroupBy` .